# Flutter: Updating firestore data

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I was trying to update a value in a document. I called the document as

```
firestoreDB.collectionGroup('marks').firestore.document('chemsitry');
```

I'm getting the document id correct but I'm getting error like

> PlatformException (PlatformException(error, Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but stud001April2019 has 1, null)),

Answer (score 0):

What you've written now boils down to:

```
firestoreDB.document('chemsitry');
```

Which means that Firestore doesn't know what collection the document is in.

---

If you want to update the `chemsitry` [sic] in the `marks` collection, you'd create a `DocumentReference` to that document with:

```
firestoreDB.collection('marks').document('chemsitry');
```

Or slightly shorter:

```
firestoreDB.document('marks/chemsitry');
```

Comment: The problem is in the `collectionGroup(...).firestore` in there. You need `collection(...).document(...)` as shown in my answer. If you've found another solution yourself, post is as an answer please.

Comment: A collection group is only useful in querying across multiple collections. To update a document you need to have a `DocumentReference`, which requires that you **know** the collection and document that you want to update. I have a feeling we're dealing with an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here, so can you please update your question to describe **what** you're trying to accomplish with this code?

Comment: I'm trying to get all student's marks in a single list and for finalization of each mark so if there is edit it in the mark they want to edit it from there itself.

Comment: So you have loaded the marks into a list, at which point you must have known both the collection that the mark is in, and the document ID. And you'll need to keep track of both, so that you can then later update that document. I can't explain it any better, so if this doesn't make it clear: update your question to show the [minimum, complete/standalone code that any of use can run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without that, we just don't have enough context.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your attention sir. I got the solution figured out

I used `docRef = snapshot.reference.path` then for updating `firestore.instance.document(docRef).updateData({
      'isVerified': true,
      'verifiedOn': _time,
    });`